# react-admin: how to customise the bulk actions

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I would like to disabled some checkbox created by a custom BulkActionsButton.
This is a simple list:

```
function CourseList(props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <List
      {...props}
      bulkActionButtons={<BulkActionButton />}
    >
      <Datagrid>
         ...some fields
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
}
```

and the `BulkActionButton`:

```
const BulkActionButton = ({
  resource,
  selectedIds,
}: BulkActionProps): ReactElement | null => {
  const { data, loading } = useGetMany(
    'shared/courses',
    selectedIds as Identifier[]
  );

  if (!data || loading) {
    return null;
  }

  const someHasBeenPaid = data.some((course) => !!course?.invoiceDate);

  return (
      <Button
        color="secondary"
        disabled={someHasBeenPaid}
        label={t('@app.manager.clientDepartment.invoiceCTA')}
      />
  );
};
```

Actually the records which have a `invoiceDate` should not be checkable first. But the checkboxes are created internally by react-admin I don't find any documentation on how to apply some filters to enable/disabled the checkboxes or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this documentation https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#isrowselectable you can use `isRowSelectable` prop on the `Datagrid` component to choose if a row is selectable for bulk actions. You get access to the record there so you can make the decision based on your data:

```
export const RecordList = props => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid isRowSelectable={ record => !record.invoiceDate }>
            ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Comment: You're welcome :) The docs of react-admin are really good and super extensive, but sometimes you won't be sure where to look until you read them **a lot** :)

Comment: Exactly :) Sometimes you get lost in it. But they make great works and big improvements lately both on the documentation and the framework. Thanks again :)

Comment: FYI, the above link seems no longer valid. Seems like it's been moved to: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Datagrid.html#isrowselectable